# Android - Google Play - Cannot install app on chromebook: Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.camera

Tags: android, google-play, chromebook

I am trying to make my app available for Chromebook devices (such as Samsung Chromebook Plus) on Google Play, but when I inspect the reason why is Unsupported, I see this message in the Google play console / Device catalog:

Reasons the device is unsupported: Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.camera

I have followed this link (https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/manifest) and tried to set up  the ApplicationManifest accordingly:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

I have some other attributes inside the  tag but I do not think they are relevant, such as  for FileProfivder,  for background services or firebase messaging or:

```
<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

I also tried without uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" but still it doesn't work.

Tried some variations for the uses-feature but no luck. Any ideas (maybe something related to a 3rd party library I am using)?